# Where in AC the charge gets its energy again?

Tags: ac, energy, charge

I'm quite new to electronics. Most of the tutorials I've watched are DC oriented and it's pretty clear that there's a voltage drop across the DC circuit. When current flows through components in DC, there's a voltage drop across each component.

Can someone help me understand how does this work in AC? Let's say I have a AC circuit with just a light bulb.

1. There's a positive current flow
2. it goes through light bulb and loses some energy
3. then the flow reverses and goes the other way
4. the light bulb still lights up

I can't seem to understand how does the light bulb in step 4 still light up when the electrons lose their energy/charge after going through it?

Comment: If you have a pipe with water flowing back and forth forced by some kind of pump - and there is a waterwheel in the middle. Will it spin? Yes, it will. In two directions alternating, but still.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Indeed, there are hydro power generators that work this way, in tidal streams ( 2 cycles/day)

Comment: Light bulb actually pulses the light, but you can not see it. The current heats the filament, which emits the light. For AC operation there're a times of high current and no current at all through the filament; but in overall it looks for us like constantly lighting because the filament does not lose the heat as fast as AC supply alternates.

Comment: For an analogy, think of a woodworking saw with triangular teeth which cut on both the forward and back stroke. Alternating current is similar in that it has the capacity to do work in both directions.

Comment: Thank you, the analogies helped me to understand the problem a little more

Comment: @Anonymous incandescent light bulbs do not flash under AC, it is not the electricity creating the light, but rather the heat. The light does not instantly cool down to a low temperature during the zero crossing. The light output is near constant with only a small AC ripple across it. Try to view an a light bulb with an slow motion camera with at least 1000 FPS

Answer (score 0):

It’s the magnitude of current flow that makes a lightbulb glow, not the polarity. If you put the lightbulb across a DC supply but swapped around the connections, would you expect the lamp not to glow the same?

Then, by the same token, AC is equivalent to that DC supply reversing its connections 50 or 60 times a second.